# Autocomplete is not working in webforms using ajax

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using VisualStudio 2017, C#, asp.net 4.6.1 and AjaxToolKit 18.1.0

And using the following code:

default.asxp

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBoxUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ServiceMethod="GetAllUsers" 
    MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" 
    CompletionSetCount="10" 
    TargetControlID="textBoxUserName" ID="AutoExtender1" runat="server" 
    FirstRowSelected="false">
</ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAllUser(string prefixText, int count)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dt.Rows.Add("Anna");
    dt.Rows.Add("Betty");
    dt.Rows.Add("Charly");
    dt.Rows.Add("David");
    dt.Rows.Add("Debbie");
    dt.Rows.Add("Donna");
    dt.Rows.Add("Gary");
    List<string> username = new List<string>();
    username = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();
    return username;
}
```

And this is what I get…

[image]

Regards
Rubenc

Comment: `GetAllUsers` vs `GetAllUser`

Comment: Changed it and same result...

Comment: Hmm...I was certain that was the issue. Can you call the service method directly? I suspected a 404 but it could be a 500 error.

Comment: Yes, I can access it directly:

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
        <ArrayOfString xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <string>Anna</string>
            <string>Betty</string>
            <string>Charly</string>
            <string>David</string>
            <string>Debbie</string>
            <string>Donna</string>
            <string>Gary</string>
        </ArrayOfString>

Comment: Found the error, it is not finding the GetAllUser method...

This is the error message:

    [InvalidOperationException: No web service found at: /default.aspx.]

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution:

I just changed

```
public static List<string> GetAllUser(string prefixText, int count)
```

to

```
public List<string> GetAllUser(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
```

and added UseContextKey="true" to the control...

and voilà!